# Unable to login in google play services when android app is downloaded from playstore

Tags: android, google-play-games

My android game app is working perfectly normal when I am installing it locally or by downloading release apk directly on phone. But, when I publish my apk on playstore then my google play services login is not working and throwing error with Result code 10002. The error dialog shows that "**Failed to sign in. Please check your network connection and try again.**"

I am struggling with this problem from past couple of days and have tried every possible solution available on internet like giving various permissions in manifest file, adding release SHA keys etc. But still unable to fix this bug. Does anyone else has face this issue before?

Comment: you have not internet in phone.